# resize image using script-fu gimp

Tags: image, autoresize, gimp, script-fu

I'm trying to prepare a script for auto-resizing image files.
I found this [LINK](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/misc/tools/script_fu/ex_10.html) but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Anyone can provide a working script that I can use as a starting point?

Comment: Why not just use ImageMagick? It's installed on most Linux distros, and readily available for all other good OSes and Windows. `convert image.jpg -resize 256x200 result.jpg`

Comment: It is, but I would definitely suggest you install it using `homebrew` if you can  - or MacPorts, though I have not used the latter.

Comment: If you are on a Mac, you can use `sips`. Type `man sips` into the Terminal.

Comment: `sips -Z 256 image.jpg` = resize `image.jpg` so neither dimension exceeds 256 pixels

Comment: @MarkSetchell wow that's amazing!

Answer (score 3):

The following function resizes the image:

```
(define (resize-image filename-in filename-out new-width new-height)
  (let* ((image    (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename-in "")))
         (drawable (car (gimp-image-active-drawable image)))
        )

     (gimp-image-scale image new-width new-height)
     (gimp-file-save   RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable filename-out "")
  )
)
```

Now, resizing all jpg's in a directory:

```
(define (file-basename filename)
  (let*
    (
      (broken-up (strbreakup filename "."))
      (wo-last-r (cdr (reverse broken-up)))
      (wo-last   (reverse wo-last-r))
      (result "")
    )
    (while wo-last
      (set! result (string-append result (car wo-last) ))
      (set! wo-last (cdr wo-last))
      (if (> (length wo-last) 0) (set! result (string-append result ".")))
    )
    result
  )
)

(define (ex_09 file-pattern new-width new-height )

  (let* ( (filelist (cadr (file-glob file-pattern 1))))

    (while (not (null? filelist))
      (let* ( (cur-file  (car filelist)) )

        (resize-image 
           cur-file 
           (string-append (file-basename cur-file) "_resized.jpg")
           100 
           100
        )

        (set! filelist (cdr filelist))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I think that this is your answer.

Comment: I can call these functions?

Answer (score 0):

The code come from this address.
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/misc/tools/script_fu/ex_09.html

Out of the box it doesn't work for me. 
I made some changes :

In the file_basename.scm file I remove some stuff I didn't get around with. 
So the resized files are created in the same directory than the original files :

```
(define (file-basename filename)
  (let*
     (
      (broken-up (strbreakup filename "."))
      (wo-last-r (cdr (reverse broken-up)))
      (wo-last   (reverse wo-last-r))
      (car broken-up) 
  )
)
```

In the ex_09.scm file :
I just used the new-width and the new-height variables.

```
(define (ex_09 file-pattern new-width new-height )
   (let* ( (filelist (cadr (file-glob file-pattern 1))))
     (while (not (null? filelist))
      (let* ( (cur-file  (car filelist)) )

      (resize-image 
        cur-file 
        (string-append (file-basename cur-file) "_resized.jpg")
        new-width
       new-height
    )

    (set! filelist (cdr filelist))
   )
  )
 )
 )
```

Hop this helps !
and thank yo René Nyffenegger for the code. 
:)